# inverse square root of band matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

this is my first post in this web site and I hope that I find an answer to my question.

I am trying to find a closed-form expression for the inverse square root of the following **symmetric** **band** **matrix** of dimension N*N:

$$
M=
\left(
\begin{array}{c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c@{\quad}}
    2  &  0  &  1  &  0  &  \cdots  &  0  &  \cdots\\
    0  &  3  &  0  &  1  &  0  &\cdots  &  0  &  \cdots\\
    1  &  0  &  3  &  0  &  1       &  \cdots & \cdots\\
    0  &  1  &  0  &  3  &  0  &  1 &  \cdots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    \vdots & & & & & & 3 & 0\\
    0  &  \cdots & & & & & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I am sorry if the above representation is not clear. For convenience, I include the matrix elements as follows:

$
M_{1,1}=M_{N,N}=2\\
M_{i,i}=3\ \mathrm{for}\ i=2,\ldots,N-1\\
M_{i,i+2}=M_{i+2,i}=1\ \mathrm{for}\ i=1,\ldots,N-2\\
M_{i,j}=0\ \mathrm{elsewhere}
$

Is there any ideas or already done work about the problem of finding the inverse square root of the matrix $M$ defined above?

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am looking for analytical expression for the elements of the inverse square root of the matrix M. I am not interested in numerical methods.

Comment: I tried to Google it but I did not find an explicit algebraic formulas, all I found is numericals methods.

Comment: One could find its inverse square root by diagonalising (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix)). I will try to look for a solution, I cannot find it back right now.

Comment: Dietrich; thank you so much for the help.